# I can not install mariadb through dnf

Tags: linux, installation, mariadb

I use "sudo dnf install mariadb" to install mariadb on fedora36 but it showed me this error:

**"  file /etc/my.cnf from install of MariaDB-common-10.9.2-1.fc36.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-connector-c-config-3.2.7-1.fc36.noarch "**

what should i do to install mariadb on my system??

Answer (score 0):

`dnf` has various options to handle situations with conflicting packages. See e.g. `--allowerasing`, `--skip-broken` and `--nobest`. Check out the [dnf man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/dnf.8.html) for a more explanation on each.

Have you consulted the Fedora documentation on installing MariaDB? (See
[Install from Fedora Main Repo](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/installing-mysql-mariadb/#install-from-fedora-main-repo)).

In particular, make sure to read the section [Installing MariaDB server from the Fedora Modular repository](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/installing-mysql-mariadb/#_installing_mariadb_server_from_the_fedora_modular_repository).